# UIScrollView "out of frame" touch areas don't respond

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm creating a `UIScrollView` as say `(320, 320)`, at origin `(0, 400)`. Assuming for now I'm designing for an iPhone 5S, with `568pts` of height.

This means the bottom portion of my scrollView does not appear in the `ViewController`'s `view` as its too tall.

Later, I shift my entire `ViewController` `view.frame` upwards by ~`152pts`, allowing us to fully reveal the scrollView and its previously hidden height.

The problem: Even though the scrollView is fully viewable now, the portion that was hidden does not respond to touch. The top half that was always visible does however function normally.

Any ideas on whats going on and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you provided, you are shifting the entire view.frame by 152 pts upwards, but the size of the view remains the same. You should also increase it's height by 152 pts.

That happens because the portion of the scrollView that is hidden, is still being drawn outside of the bounds of the view.frame.

If your frame has the default height of 568, your scrollView would be drawn from y 400 to y 720. That means the portion hidden is exactly 152, as you said. The problem is, you are moving the parent of the scrollView up by 152, but view.frame will still have a height of 568, and the scrollView will still be drawn at position 400 (in relation to the view.frame) extending to 720, which is still 152 points outside of view.frame.

If this viewController is not a childViewController of any other viewController, i'd recommend you to just move the scrollView itself up, as to avoid issues like these.